# Problema na hora de declarar 2 variáveis

Tags: python, python-3.x

O problema é o seguinte, preciso fazer uma função para somar 2 números que o usuário deverá inserir separando-os através de vírgulas, ex: 2,3, para tais valores 2 + 3 = 5, logo o resultado deverá mostrar 5 como resultado. Até essa parte foi sem problema. O problema é que o programa também precisa entender que o usuário pode colocar somente 1 número ou nenhum e essa parte esta dando erro. Segue nas linhas abaixo o código feito até o momento.

#### Código

```
def soma (num1,num2):    
    return num1 + num2

num1,num2 = [int(num1) for num1 in input("Insira 2 valores separados por vírgula: ").split(",")]

print(soma(num1,num2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *O problema é que o programa também precisa entender que o usuário pode colocar somente 1 número ou nenhum*

Bom, para isso você precisa analisar o que foi digitado, antes de converter para `int` e sair fazendo a conta.

Primeiro você pega o `input` e faz o `split`:

```
valores = input("Insira 2 valores separados por vírgula: ").split(",")
```

O que acontece se só for digitado um número? Por exemplo, se digitar somente `2`, então `valores` será uma lista com apenas um elemento: `['2']` (faça esse teste, coloque um `print(valores)` depois da linha acima e digite somente `2`).

E se o usuário não digitar nada (só der <kbd>ENTER</kbd>)? A string será vazia, e `valores` terá apenas uma string vazia: `['']`.

E se digitar qualquer coisa que não seja número, ou números mas separados por qualquer outra coisa que não seja vírgula, ou mais de 2 números? São muitos casos que pode dar tudo errado, e pelo que entendi, o programa só deve funcionar se a lista resultante tiver **exatamente** dois números separados por vírgula.

Então é isso que você deve validar: se a lista retornada por `split` tem 2 elementos, e se ambos são números inteiros. Então poderia ser algo do tipo:

```
def soma(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

valores = input("Insira 2 valores separados por vírgula: ").split(",")
if len(valores) == 2: # foram digitados 2 valores separados por vírgula, agora temos que ver se são números
    try:
        # converte para números
        num1, num2 = map(int, valores)
        # se chegou aqui, é porque a conversão para int deu certo
        print(soma(num1, num2))
    except ValueError: # se não tiver número, vai lançar um ValueError
        print('Algum dos valores digitados não é um número')
else:
    print('você deve digitar exatamente 2 valores separados por vírgula')
```

Eu resolvi somente imprimir mensagens de erro caso não tenha exatamente dois números (pois se tiver menos, não tem o que somar, e se tiver mais, não ficou claro o que é para fazer com os excedentes). Mas uma vez sabendo fazer a validação, você pode tratar cada caso individualmente da maneira que preferir.

Por exemplo, foi mencionado nos comentários que se for apenas um número, ele próprio deve ser o resultado. Então bastaria adicionar um caso especial para quando tiver apenas um valor:

```
def soma(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

valores = input("Insira 2 valores separados por vírgula: ").split(",")

if len(valores) == 1: # foi digitado apenas um valor
    try:
        print(int(valores[0])) # imprime somente o número (acho que nem precisa chamar a função soma, é desnecessário)
    except ValueError:
        print('O valor não é um número')
elif len(valores) == 2: # foram digitados 2 valores separados por vírgula, agora temos que ver se são números
    try:
        # converte para números
        num1, num2= map(int, valores)
        # se chegou aqui, é porque a conversão para int deu certo
        print(soma(num1, num2))
    except ValueError: # se não tiver número, vai lançar um ValueError
        print('Algum dos valores digitados não é um número')
else:
    print('você deve digitar exatamente 1 número, ou 2 separados por vírgula')
```

Comment: Na verdade, se só tiver 1 número ex: 2, ele deve retornar o 2 visto que será 2 + 0. Mas muito obrigado, você já me ajudou a passar de mais 1 etapa.

Comment: @user235404 Neste caso, vc deve editar a pergunta e colocar todos os critérios e o que fazer em cada um dos casos, assim as pessoas podem dar respostas mais precisas

Comment: Você realmente me ajudou muito amigo, mas pra eu fazer o caso de ele não inserir nada, eu colocaria como == none?

Comment: @user235404 Se a pessoa não digitar nada (só der ENTER), `input` retorna uma string vazia, então poderia ser algo assim: https://ideone.com/Sdvt6q

Answer (score 0):

Mudando somente um pouco

```
import sys

def soma (num1, num2):    
    return num1 + num2


try:
    s1, s2 = input("Insira 2 valores separados por vírgula: ").split(",")
except:
    print("Erro na entrada de dados.")
    sys.exit(0)

try:
    print(soma(float(s1),float(s2)))
except:
    print("Tem certeza que os valores digitados são numéricos?")
```

Comment: @AugustoVasques, obrigado pela observação. Post atualizado.